# Forming groups from a sample in R

Tags: r

I have the following problem:

I have created a sample with 35 numerical observations. From this sample, I want to draw 7 random observations. My code is:

```
my_sample <- c(1:35) 

group1 <- sample(my_sample, 7)
```

After that, I want to create a second group (group2) which again will be a vector of 7 numbers drawn from a subset of `my_sample`, excluding the observations of `group1`.

Any recommendation how can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, use `setdiff`

```
sample(setdiff(my_sample, group1), 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on **@akrun**, I managed to form 5 groups, that each contains 7 observations from `my_sample` (not so nice solution, though):

```
  my_sample <- c(1:35) 

    group1 <- sample(my_sample, 7)
    group2 <- sample(setdiff(my_sample, group1), 7)

    # creating an intermediate subset
    group_union <- union(group1, group2)

    group3 <- sample(setdiff(my_sample, group_union), 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also sample 14 numbers then split it up after. Since the sampling is done without replacement, you're guaranteed to not have any common elements between (non-overlapping) subsets of your sample.

```
two_samps <- sample(my_sample, 14)
two_samps[c(F, T)]
# [1]  2 17 20 29  1 12 33
two_samps[c(T, F)]
# [1] 22 11 18 34 27 30 28
```